# bash script to accept any input

Tags: bash, shell

How can I have a bash script to accept any characters from command line? if I type the following string `"<script_name> client_tool.c:518:        if(1)"`, I am getting "-sh: syntax error near unexpected token `('" message. It looks like bash cannot accept non-escaped "(".

I am trying to have a small script as a command which will open the grep output `(<path>:<line> <reference>)` in vi `(vi +<line>)` directly. The problem is, `<reference>` in grep can have "(" which prevents the script from running.

Comment: I tried to fix your formatting, but I wasn't sure: did you really type this string? `client_tool.c:518: if(1)`

Comment: Can you fix your formatting by putting code between backticks or on separate lines starting with four spaces, please? You can [edit] your question (see [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)). Maybe add your script, while you're at it.

Comment: I use putty, do a grep in c code, which will print the output as [path]:[line_no] [line in file]; I am trying to have a script which can take the full line in grep output (which can contain '(' ) as input and use only needed parts to open vi ( vi [path] +[line_no] ). If I use backticks, more typing which I am trying to avoid.

Comment: I meant backticks to format your question here.

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you want, replace the echo statement with your grep.

vi ${echo "client_tool.c:518: if(1)" | awk -F: '{print $1 " " $2}'}

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following script, make sure to quote parameters such as ')'.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Usage: grepvim <file:line> [search-result]
# example: grepvim client_tool.c:2 'if(1)'
file=$(echo $1 | cut -d: -f1)
line=$(echo $1 | cut -d: -f2)
vim "$file" +${line}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your grep command!
With `grep -l "something" *.c` you get a list of files.
Opening all these files in one time, use

```
vi $(grep -l "something" *.c)
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't do the way I wanted but now I have settled with a workaround. I invoke the command and the command will wait and read the input using 'read' command. This way, it can read any input characters.